# How to implement fingure print as password for the screen in iphone

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to implement fingerprint as password for the screen in iPhone?

IS it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the iPhone screen can't read fingerprints. Try a retinal scanner using the camera and flash instead :)